# Printing the message in center of the screen in FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code to print the session gone inside my flutter app

```
else if (!snapshot.hasData && snapshot.hasError) {
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text('Session TimeOut, Log back in to continue'),
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                            CupertinoPageRoute(
                              builder: (_) => LoginPage(),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: const Text('LOG IN'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
```

It is coming like this

[image: here]

I want the alert messaged Should come at the center of the screen, Any idea how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

you need to add to Column

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
```

```
Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('Session TimeOut, Log back in to continue'),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                  CupertinoPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => LoginPage(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('LOG IN'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Column height is set to `max` by default. It means that it expand to the full screen height, so Center does not do anything with it.
Also `Column` aligns its children to the top-center by default.

You have two options:

1. set `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`, to your Column, and Center will work
2. set `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` to your Column